# Android Run methods within my class every midnight.

Tags: java, android, scheduled-tasks, alarmmanager

I have some methods within an activity class. And I everyday day at midnight I want to run these methods. I wanted to do this inside the activity class:

```
public void doStuff() {

//the Date and time at which you want to execute
DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = dateFormatter .parse("2012-07-06 13:05:45");

//Now create the time and schedule it
Timer timer = new Timer();

//Use this if you want to execute it once
timer.schedule(new MyTimeTask(), date);

//Use this if you want to execute it repeatedly
//int period = 10000;//10secs
//timer.schedule(new MyTimeTask(), date, period );
}
public static class MyTimeTask extends TimerTask
{

    public void run()
    {
        //calculate new times
        //and relaunch service

    }
}
```

But as a static class I cannot access the methods and variables that are public. So can I use an Alarm Manager to do it and where can I receive the alarm so that I can run my tasks?

Comment: You'd use AlarmManager or JobScheduler to set a daily alarm at midnight.  Then if you need an Activity your BroadcastReceiver would start one.  But there is no way to make it the old activity, because there's no way to assure its still open (it probably isn't, Android has most likely killed it for resources).

Comment: @GabeSechan I dont need an activity per say but I want to run some methods that are inside the activity that do some calculations and then launch a service in the background.

Comment: I'd break those functions out to another class that both can share.  Remember that your app will almost certainly be stopped and restarted, so any data will need to be read from disk in some form or another.